# Spring Boot 2.0 Not Registering Custom Actuator Endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I've recently upgraded a project from Spring Boot 1.5.1 to 2.0.0 and our custom actuator endpoint is not getting registered. I've tried the following endpoint migration guides ([docs.spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-custom), [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Migrating-a-custom-Actuator-endpoint-to-Spring-Boot-2), and [spring.io](https://spring.io/blog/2017/08/22/introducing-actuator-endpoints-in-spring-boot-2-0)) to migrate our custom endpoint with the new approach but it doesn't work.

Here is a simplified endpoint I'm trying to register:

```
@Component
@Endpoint(id = "time")
public class TimeEndpoint {
    @ReadOperation
    public Map<String, Object> getTimeInfo() {
        return new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("time", DateTime.now(UTC));
        }};
    }
}
```

I've even tried removing the `@Component` from the class and registering it as a bean in my main `@Configuration` class like the following:

```
@Bean
public TimeEndpoint timeEndpoint() {
    return new TimeEndpoint();
}
```

When I build the project and start up, I see it registering the `/health`, `/info`, and `/actuator` endpoints, but not my `/time` endpoint. Attempting to go to `/time` or `/actuator/time` results in a 404.

```
WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto protected java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
```

I even tried upgrading to 2.0.1, but that didn't help either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

I believe, the answer by Sharan De Silva is not correct. I just spent several hours on a identical issue, because the property name is different. Should be:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: 'health,info,metrics,customendpoint'
```

Here's the official reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints

Answer (score 1):

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include={ENDPOINT-NAME}

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose your custom endpoint by adding this to your **`application.yml`** file.

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      expose: 'customendpoint,info,health'
      exclude: env
```

If you want to expose all your endpoints then change it as `expose: '*'`

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I wish this was a little clearer in the documentation and examples. Here is my final `application.properties`:

management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,time
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.info.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/

management.health.defaults.enabled=false